# CSS animation with opacity causing background image to disappear

Tags: css

I have a simple game that I am developing (just a simple pairs matching game), which has tiles that swivel around in 3d to reveal pictures on the other side of them. It all works fine, apart from now I've come to do some additional animation work I'm having a problem with the background images on the tiles disappearing. I've reduced the code down to a much simpler test case. There's still quite a lot in there, but it's mostly down to having the 3d rotation on the tile. The weird thing I can't work out is that it works fine without using opacity in the keyframe animation. As soon as I try to add opacity in there my div with the background image instantly disappears, even with opacity values of 1. I'm stumped as to why that is ... any help would be appreciated. I've tried on firefox and Edge (edge is my target browser) and they are both behaving the same. The code below is with the opacity values left in, so it's in it's broken state. Removing those will show it working as I intend without the fade at the end - the tile shows and rotates in 3d exactly as I expect with the background image showing.

```css
@keyframes tileComplete {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 540deg) scale(3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

div.tiles {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center;
  perspective: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.tiles div.tile {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #000066;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.tiles div.tile div.tile-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/test.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

div.tiles div.complete {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-name: tileComplete;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<div>
  <div class="tiles">
    <div id="tile_0" class="tile complete">
      <div class="tile-image" style="background-image: url(images/memory_game/1.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited your post to include a codesnippet, and when I run it the background fades away.

Comment: I've actually realised that it isn't he background image that is disappearing it's the entire inner div (.tile-image) that disappears. I'm going to edit my code to remove the background image and instead just have a red coloured div. As it is you probably aren't seeing any image (wasn't sure how to include an image here?), which probably just makes it look fine to you as you are seeing the outer div with the blue background fading away .

Comment: Yes I did such thing on my answer, let me know if that is what you are looking for, if not just leave a comment and we can look into it together.

Comment: Ah I see now .. sorry the snippet wasn't showing up to start with! I was slightly confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a good look at your project, I think I understood what you meant. You want the square to turn around and show the image correct? Since you are changing the opacity on the parent, it will also hide the child. In this case, the child is the image. I have added a `background-color: red` to the image container for visual purposes. I have changed the opacity of the parent within the `background-color` this changes the opacity of the parent, but doesn't change it for the child as well.

```css
@keyframes tileComplete {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 540deg) scale(3);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes tileCompleteImg {
  50% {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  }  
  100% {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  }
}

div.tiles {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center;
  perspective: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.tiles div.tile {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #000066;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.tiles div.tile div.tile-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  background-image: url("https://refuzion.nl/uploads/stock.jpeg"); 
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

div.tiles div.complete {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-name: tileComplete;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div.tiles div.img-complete {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-name: tileCompleteImg;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<div>
  <div class="tiles">
    <div id="tile_0" class="tile complete">
      <div class="tile-image img-complete"></div>
    </div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I want is the entire thing to fade out as it spins. As soon as I add Opacity into the keyframes on the parent div the red div disappears completely! Even if the opacity is set to 1. That is the bit I don't understand.

Comment: Okay so just to be sure, you want it to turn around, show the image, then fade out when it zooms right?

Comment: originally the image is on the flip side (thus the backface-visibility setting). So when you click on the tiles they spin around to reveal the image that is on the inner div. I've got all that working fine. What I'm trying to do is create an animation for when you find a match, so at that point the tiles are in the spun around position, and I just want to animate and fade them out, so I've added the keyframes. But now that I've done that adding opacity into the mix makes the red div disappear instantly.

Comment: I understand, let me see what I can do

Comment: with transitions I was able to fade the tiles out with the opacity but I'm trying to do something a little more interesting now, and it's since I've added the keyframes animation that I've had the issue. Whether it's to do with the rotate3d, or one of the 3d settings I'm not sure, but it does feel quite buggy to me ... I'm usually quite good at solving CSS issues. However it's doing in in several browsers, so seems like it might actually be intended behaviour. Just not sure what the hiccup is.

Comment: The div contains an image and the body background may also be an image of some sort, so I can't rely on colour fades instead. It has to be some sort of opacity fade.

Comment: Alright, this is kind of messy with a second keyframe animation but it does do the trick. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: it's defintely close, I've tried it with the background image in place, but I'm seeing that image all the time now, as is the -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; isn't working

Comment: actually, I put the backgorund image on the wrong div ... it's not showing at all when it's on the correct div, so it's like it was to start with. I think you're only seeing red because you've animated the outer div to become red, rather than it showing the inner div.

Comment: No I haven't, I animated the outer div to fade out to blank, and with the second animation it changed `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to `-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;` so it shows over the parent at 50% when the square has turned around. I will add an image from my own server.

Comment: I've just copied it over again ... I think I might have pasted it in wrong ... it is working now ... thanks very much!

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked, I've included a stock image from my server to visualize the solution for other people.

Comment: so ultimately it's the backface visibllity: hidden that isn't working with opacity then? I suppose that makes some sense when you stop and think about it.

Comment: I've also dropped the second keyframes animation and just assigned the backface visibility to visible to the inner div when the complete class is present on the parent. Keeps it a bit cleaner, and still works a charm ... thanks again Fuziion.

Comment: Yes the backface visibility was conflicting with the opacity, because it wants to hide the element behind the parent, and if the parent starts fading the child just gets hidden. Great job on that! I myself never really work alot with the front end stuff :3

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. I change the opacity for `div.tile`

```css
@keyframes tileComplete {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 1, 0, 540deg) scale(3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

div.tiles {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center;
  perspective: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div.tiles div.tile {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #000066;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.tiles div.tile div.tile-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/test.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

div.tiles div.complete {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-name: tileComplete;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div id="tile_0" class="tile complete">
    <div class="tile-image" style="background-image: url(images/memory_game/1.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not what OP requested.